# Making a go string in C with cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to make a go string from C. I have the pointer and the length, so if I was doing it from go, I could call the `C.GoStringN` function.

`cgo` generates the `GoString` struct, so I was wondering if I could use it directly:

```
// struct generated by cgo
typedef struct { const char *p; GoInt n; } GoString;

// I have s and n from somewhere else, can I do this ?
const char* s = ... ; // I own this and dont want go to free it
int n = ... ;

GoString st = {s, n } ;
```

I'm using this in [here](https://github.com/rstats-go/_playground_string/blob/master/src/go/src/main/main.c#L13) to make a go string out of a `char*` whose lifetime I control. The `GoString` is then used as an argument to a go function:

```
//export Nbytes
func Nbytes(s string) int {
  ...
}
```

Will go's garbage collector attempt to reclaim the memory ?

Comment: No, I don't think that GC will reclaim the memory. `const char *p` in `GoString` definition implies that the pointer won't be modified (nor freed) by Go side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go's garbage collector will not try to reclaim memory allocated using the C memory allocator.  What you are describing should be safe.  Of course, you may not be able to free the C memory, because you don't know when Go will be done with it.